# Magento Magic __set() method acting weird

Tags: magento

Magento set function is not working for any other columns except faq_question,faq_answer.
Primary key just keep on incrementing but the data is not inserting into the columns.

No matter whatever name I gave to the column names but it just keep on showing null.
Weird thing is If I manually populate the filed and use the `getFaqJugaad()` then it works. I can get the values from the database. But not set Please help. Thanks

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Gagan_Faq>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </Gagan_Faq>
    </modules>



<frontend>
    <routers>
        <faq>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Gagan_Faq</module>
                <frontName>faq</frontName>
            </args>
        </faq>
    </routers>
   <layout>
        <updates>
            <faq>
                <file>gaganfaq.xml</file>
            </faq>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <faq>
            <class>Gagan_Faq_Block</class>
        </faq>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <faq>
            <class>Gagan_Faq_Helper</class>
        </faq>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <faq>
            <class>Gagan_Faq_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>faq_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </faq>
        <faq_mysql4>
            <class>Gagan_Faq_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <dinkchika>
                    <table>gagan_faq</table>
                </dinkchika>
                <dinkchika02>
                    <table>gagan_faq_creation</table>
                </dinkchika02>
            </entities>
        </faq_mysql4>
    </models>

   <resources>
        <faq_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Gagan_Faq</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </faq_setup>
        <faq_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </faq_write>
        <faq_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </faq_read>
    </resources>        
</global>
```

This is my install script

```
<?php


$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('faq/dinkchika')} (
  `faq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `faq_question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faq_answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faq_jugaad` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`faq_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


");

$installer->endSetup();
```

indexController

```
<?php

class Gagan_Faq_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $mod = Mage::getModel('faq/faq');
        $mod->setFaqQuestion('how are 5454you?');
        $mod->setFaqAnswer('gooddsfsfsdfsfdffsd?');
        $mod->setFaqJugaad('sfsfdsfsfsdfsfdffsd?');
        $mod->save();

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Database Table

[image]

Comment: Can you check the database and see if it has actually made the column a varchar column? Else you could try to debug in the __cal function by check if the first argument is equal to "setFaqJugaad" and then var_dump and exit it after the _underscore function.

Comment: You use faq/dinkchica in the setup and faq/faq in the controller. Could you show your model and the corresponding section in config.xml?

Comment: I've added my config file.

Comment: Was the field `faq_jugaad` added later than the other fields? If so, try whether deleting `var/cache` helps.

Comment: Yes it works thanks @jurgenThelen. You can put in answers so that I can give it a green tick. Probably be helpful to someone later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Magento models don't seem to work correctly after running SQL setup scripts, e.g. a model not saving values into fields which were definitely added by the SQL script, then you most probably got trapped by Magento's [DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) caching.

Amongst other things (like `CREATE`, `INDEX` and `FOREIGN KEY` statements), Magento also caches results of time consuming `DESCRIBE table` statements. And Magento models then use such cached results (e.g. when saving) for better performance.

Now, if for whatever reason your system fails to update this DDL cache after running a SQL script which changes tables schemes (`ALTER, ADD, DROP`), your model will still use the old cache, not knowing of any changes.

Unfortunately, *none* of the clear cache buttons/links in the Magento Admin Backend allows you to clear DDL caches on demand. Neither explicitely nor implicitely (at least afaik, correct me if I'm wrong).

#### Clear DDL caches

To clear DDL caches, you can either use the swiss army knife method and simply manually delete your `var/cache/*` folders. Note that this will clear *all* existing Magento's caches, not only DDL caches.

Or you can call `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::resetDdlCache()` or one of its many derivates, like e.g. `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::getConnection()->resetDdlCache()`.

The `resetDdlCache()` method allows you to either reset the DDL caches for a single table, or for all tables at once. Be aware though, that it depends on the current state of the `_isDdlCacheAllowed` property, whether resetting will be processed.